# Using VisualSVN client without VisualSVNServer

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Is it possible to connect the VisualSVN Visual Studio client to a non-VisualSVNServer SVN instance? All of the documentation I have been able to find is VisualSVN <=> VisualSVNServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect the VisualSVN Visual Studio client to a
> non-VisualSVNServer SVN instance?

Yes.

- It is possible to connect VisualSVN plug-in to any Subversion server via HTTP(S), `svn://` or `svn+ssh://`.
- VisualSVN Server can be accessed by any Subversion client such as svn.exe, TortoiseSVN or any other HTTPS-capable Subversion clients.

  VisualSVN Server is a standard and pure Subversion server. It is based on open standards and does not try to introduce a proprietary version control system.